Cannot install alongside Windows
After disabling Secureboot, Fastboot, updating bios, even etching a new Ubuntu Distro, I cannot get the install alongside option. I have partitioned my drive to 50 gigs and afterwards even tried formating it as my :d drive. Nothing works

disable hibernate from Windows open cmd as administrator, apply powercfg.exe hibernate off, and reboot to install Ubuntu. You can select manual partitioning and empty partition to install Ubuntu.

@talaatEtman it didn't work

Please provide more details. At best, take a picture of installer screen(s) you have the problem with and describe exactly what the problem is, ie. how do you expect it to works vs. how it actually works.

You need an unformatted empty space for the install. You state you made a partition for the install and then proceeded to use it for Windows. Therefore there is no place for Ubuntu to install. BTW 50 gigs is pretty small. Add the version of Ubuntu that you are trying to install to the question with the edit function. That is a must for all questions.

This question is similar to: How to use manual partitioning during installation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
